# Cypress hangs on CI

Tags: cypress, github-actions, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Ive noticed that cypress build started to hang from time to time on CI and now it happens all the time, it just stops logging.
Im using the following stack:

- github actions + 2 ubuntu runners
- cypress 9.6.1+cypress-cucumber-preprocessor 4.3.1, node 14
- cypress dashboard for keeping test results
- headless chrome

I thought that it was related to disk space or RAM but there should be enough space(I added   free and df commands before each test). The last thing I tried - enabling debug logs, I noticed that in the end of each failed run it contains a lot of **'cypress:server:request aborting { requestId: 'request161' } +0ms'** records and then starts to print cpu/mem stats every 10 second. Has someone seen this?
[image]

Can it happen due to problems with cypress dashboard(cypress dashboard manages parallel execution)? It's strange that 2 VMs hangs at the same time...

I tried changing browser, using VMs with more RAM. Im going to try "parallel: false" and disable recording test result to cypress cloud

[image]

Comment: Running in 1 thread didn't help

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.